# How to publish byte array to the queue by using RabbitMQ management plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq, protocol-buffers, message-queue, grpc

As shown below, RabbitMQ management GUI can publish a message to the specific queue directly.[image]

The consumer of this queue consumes the message with protobuf format, which means I should publish the byte array to the queue instead of string. I have tried to convert the protobuf bytes into a base64 string but failed, is possible to tell the RabbitMQ Management GUI to convert the base64 string into bytes or there is another way to publish byte array directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ Management GUI talk to RabbitMQ Server over HTTP (HTTP is a text transfer protocol), so it is impossible to send binary data directly by Management GUI.

RabbitMQ community provide a command line tool [rabbitmq-perf-test](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test) wrapped RabbitMQ Java client, you can publish binary message with your Content-Type.

**The server pays no attention to the Content-Type header; it just passes 
it through. So make sure your client supports your Content-Type.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use any HTTP client like curl or Postman or anything else.
And just send HTTP POST request like this:

curl 'https://rabbitmq.host/api/exchanges/%2F/amq.default/publish' 
--data-raw '{"payload_encoding":"base64","vhost":"/","name":"amq.default","properties":{"delivery_mode":2,"headers":{}},"routing_key":"YOUR QUEUE NAME HERE","delivery_mode":"2","payload":"THE BASE 64 PAYLOAD HERE","headers":{},"props":{}}'